# @ used inside a self method is doing what exactly?

Tags: ruby

I saw this in some code today.

```
class Foo
  def self.bar 
    @myvar = 'x'
  end 
end
```

What exactly is this accessing? As far as I can tell, this isn't accessible form instance methods.  What's this called (something google-able) as I cant seem to find examples of this anywhere else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `@myvar` syntax identifies `myvar` as an instance variable so the real question is this:

> What is `self` inside a class method?

And the answer is "`self` is the class object". So, `@myvar` is an instance variable of the `Foo` class object. If you add another class method:

```
class Foo
    def self.pancakes_house
        @myvar
    end
end
```

And then do this:

```
Foo.bar
puts Foo.pancakes_house
```

You'll see `x` on the standard output.

Comment: follow up question: is there a 'belief' in the Ruby community about whether using them is good practice?  (It immediately jumps out at me as being not threadsafe.)

Comment: @John: I don't know if there is a general consensus, I've never needed such a thing. Maybe if, for some reason, you need a class variable that is hidden from instances you'd do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

A class is also an object, so you are setting a instance variable in class Foo.

```
>> Foo.bar
>> Foo.instance_variable_get("@myvar") 
=> 'x'
```

Now, for a typical use, add `class << self; attr_accessor :myvar; end` to your class and you can write:

```
>> Foo.bar
>> Foo.myvar
=> 'x'
```

Answer (score 1):

For googling, this is sometimes called a "class instance variable". That is, an instance variable of an object that just happens to be a class.